# How to create two C executable with different -D variable=value using makefile

Tags: c, makefile

My code uses one macro which I am defining during the build as follows.

```
gcc -D VAR=1000 main.c -0 main
```

But I want to create two executable, one with VAR=1000 and other with VAR=2000. Lets say executable names would be main_1000 and main_2000.

How can I do that using Makefile.

My attempt to do that is as follows. But it does not work and gives me an error.

```
gcc -g   -c -o main.o main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:16: error: ‘VAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:5:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g

all: main_1000 main_2000

main_1000: main.o
    $(CC) -D VAR=1000 -o main_1000 main.o $(CFLAGS)

main_2000: main.o
    $(CC) -D VAR=2000 -o main_2000 main.o $(CFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main_1000: main.o
```

This implies that you already expect `main.o` to be there. Since there's no rule for compiling a `c` file to an `o` file, `make` uses its implicit rule, which doesn't include the definition. What you want instead is this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g

all: main_1000 main_2000

main_1000: main.c
    $(CC) -D VAR=1000 -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

main_2000: main.c
    $(CC) -D VAR=2000 -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```